# Postgres update using InstantSQL RMCobol

Tags: sql, postgresql, cobol

I need to update a column in Postgres using fields from the same table and cobol fields

```
    update mytable
    set col1 = (col2 * ?) + (col3 * ?) + (col4 * ?);
```

Here ? are the cobol fields.
col2, 3, and 4 are integers and col1 is a decimal (5,2)

I have bound the cobol parameters as below:

```
      *bind parameters
        SQL BIND PARAMETER sql-QueryHandle
          1 sql-Numeric sql-Param-Input WS-fld1 OMITTED
          2 sql-Numeric sql-Param-Input WS-fld2 OMITTED
          3 sql-Numeric sql-Param-Input WS-fld3 OMITTED.
```

Cobol field values are

```
1. field 1 = 020.00
2. field 2 = 030.00
3. field 3 = 040.00
```

The program runs without errors but the result shows as 0 for col 1 all the time.

But in the same SQL if I directly have cobol values as below it col1 has correct values:

```
    update mytable
    set col1 = (col2 * 020.00) + (col3 * 030.00) + (col4 * 040.00);
```

I have tried binding with both sql-Numeric and sql-Decimal but no difference in output.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Cobol fields and PostgreSQL columns match in terms of precision/scale and data type. For integer columns, use sql-Integer, and for decimal columns, sql-Decimal.
Check that the values of WS-fld1, WS-fld2, and WS-fld3 are valid prior to executing the SQL query. Use sql-Decimal as the output argument if col1 is a decimal.
Try this;

```
*bind parameters
SQL BIND PARAMETER sql-QueryHandle
  1 sql-Integer sql-Param-Input WS-fld1 OMITTED
  2 sql-Integer sql-Param-Input WS-fld2 OMITTED
  3 sql-Integer sql-Param-Input WS-fld3 OMITTED
  4 sql-Decimal sql-Param-Output WS-Col1 OMITTED.
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, the integer col2/col3/col4 when multiplied with cobol decimal gave 0. When I did a cast (col1 to decimal) and then multiplied with cobol decimal it worked fine.